# Display array values in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am generating and display crystal report from my asp.net application. In the code, i have a array of numbers that I want to be able to display in the report. so if in my code I have int[] {1,4,5,6,8,10 } I want to somehow pass this array to crystal report so that we have 6 rows in the details section of the report where each row is showing one value from the array..so we will have a report like:

```
1
4
5
6
8
10
```

is this possible..how..please help

Answer (score 1):

If you are doing this from .Net, you should be able to achieve this by creating a custom dataset and data table, filling the values in the data table as you require, and then provide the datatable as source to your Crystal report.

Have a look at some of these articles, they should help you in the direction you need

Ignore the section where the database corrections are mad.

Focus on the section where it sets the datasource

```
// Setting data source of our report object
objRpt.SetDataSource(Ds);
```

- [Crystal Report with DataSet and
  DataTable using C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CrystalReportNDataTable.aspx)
- [Creating Crystal Reports using C#
  with Datasets](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CreatingCrystalReports.aspx)

Comment: thanks..i am confused though..you have to do both the ado.net data set (through the gui) and set the data source in the report as well?
but if you just set it through the code then how will you design the report because it wont show the available fields etc..

Comment: you use the xsd to design the report...then pass in the actual data at runtime.